# Making a nested array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Probably my question is too much common or easy for you, but I really have no idea how to do it. Trying all everything I know and lots of googling didn't help me.

I just need a nested array.

Here is my PHP code:

**EDITED**
Corrected: $data['product_names'][$language['language_id']][] = array(

```
$data['product_names'] = array();

foreach ($data['languages'] as $language) {
    $product_names_info = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategoryMultiLang($this->request->get['product_id'], $language['language_id']);

    if ($product_names_info) {
        $data['product_names'][$language['language_id']][] = array(
            'category_id' => $product_names_info['category_id'],
            'language_id' => $product_names_info['language_id'],
            'name'        => $product_names_info['name']
        );
    }
}

print_r($data['product_names']);
```

The result that I get:

```
Array
(
    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [category_id] => 
                    [language_id] => 
                    [name] => 
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [category_id] => 
                    [language_id] => 
                    [name] => 
                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [category_id] => 
                    [language_id] => 
                    [name] => 
                )

        )

    ...
```

The result should look like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [language_id] => 1
            [category_id] => 8
            [name] => book
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [language_id] => 5
            [category_id] => 188
            [name] => magazine
        )

...
)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [language_id] => 1
            [category_id] => 8
            [name] => buch
        )

...
```

**UPDATED**
The result of `print_r($product_names_info);`  inside `foreach ($data['languages'] as $key => $language) {`

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [language_id] => 5
            [category_id] => 8
            [name] => Gecelik
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [language_id] => 5
            [category_id] => 188
            [name] => Sabahlık
        )

    ...

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [language_id] => 2
            [category_id] => 8
            [name] => لباس خواب
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [language_id] => 2
            [category_id] => 188
            [name] => Sabahlık
        )
```

Thanks for any kind help.

Comment: Can we see the result you are getting aswell?

Comment: what's the actual result? however you seem need to remove this `[$language]`

Comment: what's your issue here?

Comment: $language is an array, you used it as a key, I think that's the problem

Comment: @rahulsm seems that `$language` is not an array, maybe it's a string

Comment: but OP uses it as an array check once '$product_names_info = .....' line to the end

Comment: I updated my question with the result that I get

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$data['product_names'] = array();

foreach ($data['languages'] as $language) {
    $product_names_info = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategoryMultiLang($this->request->get['product_id'], $language['language_id']);

    if ($product_names_info) {
        foreach ($product_names_info as $key => $value) {
            $data['product_names'][$language['language_id']][] = array(
                'category_id' => $value['category_id'],
                'language_id' => $value['language_id'],
                'name'        => $value['name'],
            );
        }

    }
}

print_r($data['product_names']);
```

I think you were missing foreach for the data you fetched into var `$product_names_info`

Comment: Hey, thanks! I tried you approach but second array is empty as before.

Comment: Can you update your question with output of $product_names_info also?

Comment: yes, I tried both, second array give the same empty result

Comment: Can you update your question with output of $product_names_info also?

Comment: Are you sure, the result you get is output of $product_names_info array? i.e. title of **The result that I get:** is $product_names_info's output?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157274/discussion-between-kardo-and-rahulsm).